# android listview item open, back animation

Tags: android, listview, animation

Does someone know how to implement the [secret](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ly.secret.android) app's animation?
  On clicking the comment button in the list item, the current change to the comment page constantly, likes in one page. I like this design, can you give me some hints how can I go forward with this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, after a small look i can only say this. It's definitely an new activity (when clicking on the post button). Why, logging the app says me this:

```
I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {cmp=ly.secret.android/.ui.PostActivity (has extras)} from pid 19652
```

I think that the animation is made using transitions between activities using `overridePendingTransition` method (see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29))